# TVCardView rounded corners strange behaviour

Tags: uicollectionview, tvos, apple-tv

I'm setting up a new tvOS app with a `UISplitViewController` and a `UICollectionView` as a detail view. To achieve some nice out-of-the-box focus behaviour, I'm trying to use `TVCardView` inside the `UICollectionViewCell` and adding an image view and a label to the card views content view (in interface builder). That works, but the problem is that the card views always applies rounded corners to the content once they have been selected. Initially all views have sharp corners, but as soon as a cell has been selected, it switches to rounded corners.
First of all, I don't even want rounded corners and in Apples examples, I never see those rounded corners anyway: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvuikit/tvcardview
But even then, it's kind of useless to have rounded corners only partially after selection.

Has anyone experience with `TVCardView` and knows about this strange behaviour? I cannot find any example code or more detailed documentation. I also tried to use `TVLockupView` instead, but that doesn't seem to be supported by interface builder.

Comment: From what I've seen, you don't even have to be using a UICollectionView. Just dropping two `TVCardView` instances into a view, on app launch the one card will be focused, but the other will not and the corners will not be rounded. Two workarounds I can think of - provide my own background for the content view (will not exactly match, and I'd have to color it) or sniff the `TVCardView.contentView`'s superview, which is a sibling to the background view. Then set the corner radius to 12 manually. But that's potentially just as bad.

Answer (score 1):

This was an SDK bug and is fixed in newer versions of Xcode/tvOS - just verified in Xcode 13.2.1 Simulator.

For older versions you have to work around it (I mentioned one here in the comment - [TVCardView rounded corners strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64801624/tvcardview-rounded-corners-strange-behaviour#comment120147879_64801624))

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the issue that:

typically you have a UIImageView **inside** of the card view.

Confusingly, you have to TURN OFF

- adjust on ancestor focus
- user interaction enabled

**on the UIImageView**.

If you don't, the image view will "doubly" expand, when the card view expands!

This can be incredibly confusing, as it may/may not round corners when "not doubly expanded" and often there are weird margin issues, parts of the image never visible and so on.